# Syntax error, unrecognized expression: ${languageLabel}

Tags: javascript, jquery

The console gives me an error while attempting to change the textnode's text value of javascript template expression i.e `${foo}`

**Js**

```
            // this.textContent here gives ${languageLabel}
            var variable = UI.patternMatch(textNodes_elRef);
            $(variable).nodeValue ="language";
        });


patternMatch : function(textNode) {
    var templateRegex = /\${([\S\s]*?)\}/g;
    return $(textNode).contents().filter(function() {
        if($(this.textContent).match(templateRegex)){
          // ** How do i return the textnode with only matched pattern**
        }
```

So to sum up basically i want to change the textnode's textValue of ${languagelabel} to language but i get the error as ** Syntax error, unrecognized expression: ${languageLabel}**

Comment: What does `UI.patternMatch(this.textContent)` return?

Comment: I'm guessing `${languageLabel}` is being passed to `$()`, because I get the same error when I call `$("${languageLabel}")`.

Comment: Also, `.textValue` isn't a jQuery method. You might be looking for `.text()`.

Comment: @Ian it returns $languagelabel which is teh textnode i want to replace with "language"

Comment: @Ian ur right i was testing it but the correct method is nodeValue

Comment: Does it actually return the `TextNode`, or does it return text? For example, what is shown when you use `alert(variable);` after your declaring line?

Comment: it just returns text i think thats what the problem is

Comment: @Ian my patternMatch() loops through the textnode and return me the matching textnode but it returns me only text how do i make it return textNode with matching pattern ? thanks in advance.. see my edited question?

Comment: I think you should use the `.contents()` so that you have the text contents as Nodes - http://api.jquery.com/contents/ .

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27745/discussion-between-user2125700-and-ian)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just store a reference to the `textNode` instance that matched and return it after the loop and you don't have to use jQuery only to modify the textNode's `nodeValue` property. Here's an example http://jsfiddle.net/LAud7/.

```
function patternMatch(el) {
    var templateRegex = /\${([\S\s]*?)\}/g,
        nodeFound;

    $(el).contents().each(function() {
        if (templateRegex.test(this.nodeValue)) {
            nodeFound = this;
            return false;
        }
    });

    return nodeFound;
}

patternMatch($('#test')).nodeValue = 'replaced content';
```

*Please note that with this approach, if the `textNode` containing `${...}` contains other text as well, it won't give the expected result because all the text will be replaced so you need to make sure that the `${...}` is contained within it's own `textNode`.*

Comment: i still find the same error .. i pass in the textnode text content and also tried passing in the element itself but it gives me an error

Comment: What does `alert(typeof patternMatch(...));` return?

Comment: i finally got it .. thanks for your suggestion ..It worked .. i passed the node in pattern match and loop through each node and get a reference to matched node and return it back and made some changed and it worked ..Thank so much +1

Comment: I'm glad I could help. However, are the `${...}` always contained within their own text nodes alone, without any other text?

Comment: yh they always within their textnodes